# TSQL xQuery how to I get the root/document node

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have an XML Field that contains data similar to how .Net constructs controls within forms.  Suppose you have a windows Form, you can add multiple controls to the form and they show up under the .Controls property.  Some of the controls themselves can also have controls such as panels, group boxes etc.  Similar to what is shown in the xml below.

```
<Form>
<Name>MyForm</Name>
<TabCtrl>
    <Name>Tab1</Name>
    <Controls>
        <TextboxCtrl>
            <Name>MyTextBox</Name>
            <Location>3,10</Location>
            <Tag>34</Tag>
        </TextboxCtrl>
        <Label>
            <Name>MyLabel</Name>
            <Location>23,3</Location>
            <Tag>19</Tag>>
        </Label>
        <Panel>
            <Name>myPanel</Name>
            <Controls>
                <TextboxCtrl>
                    <Name>MyTextBox2</Name>
                    <Location>36,210</Location>
                    <Tag>34</Tag>
                </TextboxCtrl>
            </Controls>
        </Panel>
    </Controls>
</TabCtrl>
<TabCtrl>
    <Name>Tab2</Name>
    <Controls>
        ...
    </Controls>
</TabCtrl>
```

There are thousands of rows in a DB table each with xml that itself consists of up sometimes 1000’s of “controls”.  I’m looking for a way to query for TabCtrl/Name node when that TabCtrl contains a control that has the Tag of 34.
I can limit the rows by this query using xPath

```
Select theXML from ViewTable where theXML.exist('//Tag[.="34"]') = 1
```

Further, I can get the Name of the control rather than the entire xml with this:

```
Select theXML.query('//*[Tag="34"]/Label/text()') as 'Control Name'from ViewTable where theXML.exist('//Tag[.="34"]') = 1
```

How do I get the TabCtrl/Name ?  The path from the element that contains the matching Tag could go through 1-n levels of Controls nodes so using the Xpath statement won’t work.  The TabCtrl will all ways be a direct child of the Form node

Comment: Do you want to return controls at any depth with a Tag of 34, or only controls at a particular depth with a Tag of 34?

Comment: BTW, I don't get the point of your where clause, because the xpath used in select clause already validate for the same

Comment: the where clause is used to eliminate other rows that do not contain the Tag = 34.  This happens first.  Of of the 1000 rows in the DB only 2 actually have a Tag of 34 so the result set is 2 rows.  Without it I would have 1000 rows all empty but 2.

Comment: @MtnManChris ah sure, I missed that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Solutions :**

One possible way to get the text from `TabCtrl/Name` containing a control that has the Tag of 34 :

```
Select theXML.query('//TabCtrl[Controls/*/Tag="34"]/Name/text()') as 'Control Name'
```

Or if you need to get to the `<TabCtrl>` starting from it's descendant then you can always climb up the tree using `parent::element_name` or `ancestor::element_name` or `..` :

```
Select theXML.query('//*[Tag="34"]/ancestor::TabCtrl/Name/text()') as 'Control Name'
```

**Difference between axes mentioned above :**

- `parent::element_name` : Go *one* level up to a *specific* parent element
- `ancestor::element_name` : Go *one or more* level up to a *specific* ancestor element
- `..` : Go *one* level up to a parent element with *any* name

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support the ancestor axis

Comment: fyi this error is given on the bottom method:  The XQuery syntax 'ancestor' is not supported.   The top method however works like a charm.  Thank you

Comment: @DanField Thanks, didn't use xpath with SQL much, now I know SQL server doesn't support ancestor axis

Comment: @DanField Thanks for the info, didn't use xpath with SQL much

Answer (score 1):

Shred the XML on `Form/TabCtrl` using [nodes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), check the existence of `Tag=34` for each shredded node using [exist()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) and finally get the value from `Form/TabCtrl/Name` with the [value()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) function.

```sql
select TC.X.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
from YourTable as T
  cross apply T.theXML.nodes('/Form/TabCtrl') as TC(X)
where TC.X.exist('*//Tag/text()[. = "34"]') = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0de7/1)

Comment: This doesn't work in that it returns the all the names of the tabs in the entire XML not just those that contain Tag=34.  Similar to theXML.query('//TabCtrl[//Tag="34"]/Name')

Comment: Doesn't the fiddle return your expected names? Can you give an example where this code does it wrong and what the expected result should be?

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the `TabCtrl/Name` for any TabCtrl that has a Controls node that has a grand child Tag that =s 34:

```
DECLARE @theXML XML = '<Form>
<Name>MyForm</Name>
<TabCtrl>
    <Name>Tab1</Name>
    <Controls>
        <TextboxCtrl>
            <Name>MyTextBox</Name>
            <Location>3,10</Location>
            <Tag>34</Tag>
        </TextboxCtrl>
        <Label>
            <Name>MyLabel</Name>
            <Location>23,3</Location>
            <Tag>19</Tag>>
        </Label>
        <Panel>
            <Name>myPanel</Name>
            <Controls>
                <TextboxCtrl>
                    <Name>MyTextBox2</Name>
                    <Location>36,210</Location>
                    <Tag>34</Tag>
                </TextboxCtrl>
            </Controls>
        </Panel>
    </Controls>
</TabCtrl>
<TabCtrl>
    <Name>Tab2</Name>
    <Controls>
        ...
    </Controls>
</TabCtrl>
</Form>'


Select @theXML.query('//TabCtrl/Controls/*[Tag="34"]/../../Name') as 'Control Name'
```

Output:

```
<Name>Tab1</Name>
```

I'm not 100% sure that's what you're looking for, but this is probably the general pattern you want to follow here, with an additional query if you need to get more deeply nested Tag=34 nodes.

Comment: yes but if it is not a grand child it won't work.  Since I don't know at what level it appears the "upward" path is variable.

Comment: Yeah, this is a challenge in SQL Server bcause it has no support for the ancestor axis.  I think @MikaelEriksson's solution should work.